# How to stub isFile from fs.statSync

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, stubbing, sinon-chai

I am writing a unit test for file and path manipulations, but I cannot stub `isFile` in  `fs.statSync(filePath).isFile()` .

I am getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: isFile is not defined
```

My code is :

```
const readFiles = fs.readdirSync(directoryPath);
      readFiles.map(file => {
        filePath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), `${directoryPath}/${file}`);
        const isFile = fs.statSync(filePath).isFile();
        if (!isFile) {
          const filesList = fs.readdirSync(filePath).map(fileName => file + '/' + fileName);
          files = [
            ...files,
            ...filesList,
          ];
        } else {
          files = fs.readdirSync(directoryPath);
        }
      });
```

here is my before test code, to create the stubs and assign to rewired :

```
beforeEach(() => {
    helpers.__set__({
      'fs.statSync': sinon.stub().returns(true),
      isFile: sinon.stub().returns(true),
      'path.resolve': sinon.stub().returns('/a/b/c'),
    });
  });
```

please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your stub for `fs.statSync` works as intended, it provides `true`. So you can't call `isFile` on it.

So I suppose you can simply mock a function `isFile` in the object provided by `statSync` that would return true:

```js
'fs.statSync': sinon.stub().returns({ isFile: () => true})
```